# Replacing an existing image in an Xcode Project

Tags: xcode, image

I am trying to update an Xcode project.  The update is to replace an image that is displayed in a static window.  I replaced the image being called, the new image has the same name and size, but when I open the window, the image does not fill the entire window like the original image did.  I a new developer in general, but a total newbie when it comes to XCode.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing an image file in a Xcode project can be done as:

1. Go to File in Xcode using the Project Navigator.
2. Right click the file and pick "Show in Finder"
3. Drag new file into as same folder as the old file. (make sure the old file and the file have the same name)
4. Say yes, you want to replace the file.

And your done.

Compile and run will show the new image. I've done this hundreds of times, usually updating placeholder images and never had any trouble.

As for your particular problem, you didn't describe the steps you used to replace the image, so I can't testify on that, but if you do the above and don't get the results you want it's going to be from a bad image file (different size, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried your method, can't remember exactly how I replaced it before, but it seemed to work, other than the the image not being sized correctly. I tried it with a jpg rather than png. I am updating a placeholder also, and the size is the same.  Your instructions make sense, and this seems to be straight forward, so it's quite puzzling why it won't work.

Comment: I added a bigger image and even that still does not fill the entire window

Comment: I be happy to help you troubleshoot and find the issue, but without more information, I don't know where to begin. My mistake is always the images, but could code have changed which not longer scales the image? Or the first image was small, so the frame for the `UIImageView` is set to the size of the first smaller image and needs to be increased in size for the second image?